# how to strip pre and post garbage from XML string

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have some XML string which contains some garbage before and after the xml string. Is there a way to trim those values so that I could successfully process the XML.

**Current XML:**

```
--35DEUofWdwzmcKmxp4z2RsI7REh-Y5atOY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="uidoc6379937292471437665.xml5114968690793017785.tmp"

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<product xmlns="http://www.example.com/abc/2014/product">
    <timestamp>2017-04-06T04:00:02.387Z</timestamp>
</product>
--35DEUofWdwzmcKmxp4z2RsI7REh-Y5atOY--
```

**New XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<product xmlns="http://www.example.com/abc/2014/product">
    <timestamp>2017-04-06T04:00:02.387Z</timestamp>
</product>
```

Comment: Ideally, you should correctly extract the XML from the original MIME message, so this isn’t an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you know about the xml. If it's like the above you can just do:

```
int start = source.IndexOf("<?xml");
source = source.Remove(0, start);
int end = source.IndexOf("</product>") + "</product>".Length;
source = source.Remove(end, source.Length-end);
```

A little more error checking would probably be appropriate.
I am assuming C# here, other programming languages have similar constructs.

Comment: You should tag your question with java, then. It's been a long time since I did java, but as I remember string handling is pretty similar to C#.

Comment: could you tag this with java please as i am not familiar on it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it either. I don't know if I'm allowed to edit questions. It tells me the edit queue is full.

Comment: OK. I managed to add it, but it says it's only visible to me until it has been reviewed.

Answer (score -1):

Below Code snippet should help eliminating the unwanted characters of XML string. Please share your comments, if there is anything.

```
int start = xml.indexOf("<?xml");
String preGarbageValue = xml.substring(0, start);
xml = StringUtils.stripStart(xml, preGarbageValue);
int end = xml.lastIndexOf("</product>")+"</product>".length();

String postGarbageValue = xml.substring(end, xml.length());

xml = StringUtils.stripEnd(xml, postGarbageValue);
```

Comment: An answer consisting only of a code dump, with no explanation, is not a good answer.

Comment: the code causing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 . Any helps is greatly appreciated